# Custom push notification in iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I am from Android background, now working in cross platform mobile application. I don't have any knowledge in iOS. In my application, I need to customize the push notification in displayed in the notification bar. In Android I achieve this. Can any one help me in iOS?

This is my json data :

```
{
"Test1":"Value 1",
"Test2":"Problem:[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]"
}
```

Output should be :  Value 1 --> b ,d

What I have tried

```
- (void)handleBackgroundNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
{
     NSMutableString *alert = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    if ([notification objectForKey:@"Test1"]){
        [alert appendString:(NSString *)[notification objectForKey:@"Test1"]];
    }
}
```

I dont know if this is correct.

Comment: It's unclear from your question if you are asking about remote notifications (Apple Push Notifications) or local notifications. Are you sending the message from a server to the app?

Comment: i am using Java_PNS.jar in server side then its APNS notification?. I am not sure

Comment: The contents of the push notification is set by the server. So this is really an APNS server question, and it has nothing to do with Xcode, which is just a IDE.

Comment: Yeah i am sending message to IOS device using registered ID by mobile from APNS

Comment: And it's typed iOS, not IOS :)

Comment: @KPM :( but its not my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending Apple Push Notifications from your server to an iOS application. Apple Push Notifications offer much less freedom than Android's GCM. The JSON you are sending should look like this :

```
{"aps":{"alert":"message","badge":3,"sound":"sound-file-name"},"custom-property":"custom-value"}
```

The only parameter used to display the notification is the "alert" parameter (there are some minor variations - the "alert" parameter can be a dictionary by itself and define some additional parameters used for displaying the message, but none of them is a custom parameter).

You can add custom parameters, as shown above, but they will not be shown in the notification (they will be passed to the method that handles the notification if the user taps on the notification). Unlike Android, you don't write the code that displays the notification. In iOS it's part of the operating system.

You can further read about the notification payload [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1).

Comment: still i am receiving as JSON format. whether I need to do some customisation in client side?. Now Server side response is perfect.

Comment: @RED.Skull I looked at the JSON in the link you supplied. It's a valid APNS payload. What's the question?

Comment: i am getting notification. but i need to format that notification in Notification bar. I gone through some links "didReceiveRemoteNotification" this method will help to receive remote notification and show in notification bar. You have idea on this. Please share... still issue was not closed

Comment: @RED.Skull `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called after the user taps the notification, so it has no effect on the format of the displayed notification in the notification bar. As I said in my answer, you can't control the format of the displayed notification programmatically in your app.

Comment: @RED.Skull Perhaps what you read about `didReceiveRemoteNotification` refers to what happens when the notification arrives while the app is already running in the foreground. In that case nothing is displayed in the notification bar, and `didReceiveRemoteNotification` gets called with the notification's payload as a parameter. This is the only case in which you get to decide programmatically how to display the notification to the user. In the other cases (app not running or app in background) you have no control.

Comment: So notification is customized only from server not in client for displaying in notification bar. Am i right ?